# Multiple categories in Url

Tags: yii2

I want to create links something like that:

http://example.com/cat1/itemname-1

http://example.com/cat1/cat2/itemname-2

http://example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/itemname-3

http://example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/[..]/cat9/itemname-9

How rule looks like in yii2 UrlManager and how to create links for this?

```
Url::to([
    'param1'    => 'cat1',
    'param2'    => 'cat2',  
    'param3'    => 'cat3',
    'slug'      => 'itemname',
    'id'        => 3
]);
```

Above code is really bad for multiple category params.
I add that important is only last param it means ID.

Controller looks like that:

```
public function actionProduct($id)
{
    echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below url rule would to this trick but you have to build the "slug" with the categories within your controller:

```
'rules' => [
    ['route' => 'module/controller/product', 'pattern' => '<slug:(.*)+>/<id:\d+>', 'encodeParams' => false],
]
```

Generate the Url:

```
yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['/module/controller/product', 'slug' => 'cat1/cat2/cat3', 'id' => 1])
```

The output would be:

`example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/1`

Comment: Nice solution its working but if change pattern to 
`'pattern' => '<slug:(.*)+>/<id:\d+>-<name:[a-z0-9\-_\.]+>'`
shorts url like `cat1/cat2/cat3/1-oddasd-das` works but `cat1/cat2/cat3/1-oddasd-das-ads-sad-sa-d-sda` return 404 error